# How do I upgrade Nookling Junction?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I've had the game for 10 days and I want to know if I can upgrade nookling junction.

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can. To upgrade it into [T&T Mart](https://nookipedia.com/wiki/T%26T_Mart), you need to spend 12,000 Bells at Nookling Junction, 10,000 home desposit to Tom Nook, and 10 days have passed since the town's creation.